# solrnet crashes if you add a lot of filter queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, solr, solrnet

We use **solrnet** in our ASP.NET Core backend. In the `startup.cs` it is initialized like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSolrNet<SolrPunt>(solrEndpointAddressForPunt, setup =>
     {
           setup.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentialsBase64);                
     });  
}
```

The search code itself is quite simple. We inject an instance of `ISolrOperations<solrEndpointAddressForPunt>`, and use it accordingly:

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions
{
    FilterQueries = new List<ISolrQuery>()
};

// FilterQueries are added 

var solrResponse = await solrOperationsVoorPunten.QueryAsync("*:*", queryOptions);
```

This all works fine and we receive results correctly.

However, if we add a lot of filter queries, like more than 105, it throws an exception:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

I'm wondering why this is and how this can be fixed.

It has nothing to do with XML/JSON setting, as it works perfectly with a small amount of filter queries.

I'm thinking it has to do with the limit of a GET request. But then I read that normally it should then switch to a POST automatically? Can I tell solrnet to always use POST? And if so, how to do that in ASP.NET core?

Or is there another limitation that is causing this?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it. Instead of concatenating the fields in a for loop:

```
solrQueryByField = solrQueryByField || new SolrQueryByField(filterVeld, filterValue);
```

... I simply use `SolrQueryInList`:

```
queryOptions.FilterQueries.Add(new SolrQueryInList(filterVeld, filterValues));
```

With this change, it started working...